# What logging system should I use in C# so I could view logs in Azure?

Tags: c#, azure

I read about System.Diagnostics but that is not helping or may be I am implementing it wrong.

I am currently doing:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write( "Log Start" );
```

Can someone Guide here?

I need to print my logs in Azure.

Comment: Have a look at [Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/).

Comment: It doesn't show the log

Comment: It doesn't look like you did much research before asking your question. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-log-audit and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-of-diagnostic-logs

Comment: It would help if you would describe what kind of application we are talking about. Is it a web app, a web job? a Function, a container...

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to your app / server and choose `Settings > Diagnostics logs.` and enable the options you need.
You can then access the logs directly on the server or via an FTP that Azure creates.

There is official documentation from Azure for this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log

I suggest you give it a go with the official documentation.